# Oracle APEX - dynamic where clause based on the page item

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Is there a way to construct a dynamic where clause based on a page item value?

Perhaps something using CASE WHEN?

```
SELECT a.ID, a.NAME
FROM Table1 a
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE))='TYPE1' OR 
           mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE))='TYPE2' THEN
        NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM   Table2 b
          WHERE  b.id = a.id            
             AND  b.type_id = :P2_TEST_TYPE
             AND mypackage.get_category_id(b.parent_id) <> mypackage.get_category_id(:P2_PARENT_ID)
             AND b.status = 'NEW'
       )
  WHEN mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE))='TYPE3' THEN
       NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM   Table2 b
          WHERE  b.id = a.id            
             AND  b.type_id = :P2_TEST_TYPE
             AND b.status = 'NEW'
       )
 END
```

How could I do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

Instead of `CASE`, use union of both `SELECT` statements, but each of them has its own (additional) condition - the one you meant to put into `CASE`.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.NAME
FROM Table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
          FROM   Table2 b
          WHERE  b.id = a.id            
             AND b.type_id = :P2_TEST_TYPE
             AND mypackage.get_category_id(b.parent_id) <> mypackage.get_category_id(:P2_PARENT_ID)
             AND b.status = 'NEW'
             AND mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE)) IN ('TYPE1', 'TYPE2')
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1
          FROM   Table2 b
          WHERE  b.id = a.id            
             AND b.type_id = :P2_TEST_TYPE
             AND b.status = 'NEW'
             AND mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE)) = 'TYPE3'
  );
```

Comment: could you please help me with my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763721/contiditional-where-clause-withmore-than-3-conditions