# Contiditional WHERE clause with more than 3 conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query with a conditional WHERE clause where I select users from Table1 based on a page item.

If a page item has a value of TYPE1 or TYPE2, I select the users from Table1 that are not in Table2, meeting first condition,
and if a user is of TYPE3, then I select users from Table2 that are not in Table2 under a second condition.

Now I need to add two more types TYPE4 and TYPE5 but the difficulty is that if the users is in either of these types, they
should not already exist in Table2 with a `status='NEW'`

```
      SELECT 1
      FROM   Table2 b
      WHERE  b.id = a.id            
         AND b.type_id = :P2_TEST_TYPE
         AND b.status = 'NEW'`
```

but should be in role 'PRIMARY' and 'SECONDARY' respectively:

```
mypackage.get_role(a.id) = 'PRIMARY' AND mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE))='TYPE4'
```

AND

```
mypackage.get_role(a.id) = 'SECONDARY' AND mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE))='TYPE5'
```

The query that takes care of TYPE1, TYPE2, and TYPE3 is below. How can I encorporate the conditions for TYPE4 and TYPE5 into this query:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.NAME
FROM Table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
      FROM   Table2 b
      WHERE  b.id = a.id            
         AND b.type_id = :P2_TEST_TYPE
         AND mypackage.get_category_id(b.parent_id) <> mypackage.get_category_id(:P2_PARENT_ID)
         AND b.status = 'NEW'
         AND mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE)) IN ('TYPE1', 'TYPE2')
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1
      FROM   Table2 b
      WHERE  b.id = a.id            
         AND b.type_id = :P2_TEST_TYPE
         AND b.status = 'NEW'
         AND mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE)) = 'TYPE3'
  );
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: Don't you have the option to make that kind of conditional selection on the service level? (if you have one)

Comment: Even if there isn't an app where you can incorporate that kind of logic then what keeps you from creating two or more separate queries to break down the coplexity? In any case if you need to write your query in this way then i believe you will find the sql switch case statement very useful. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: It might be easier to switch to PL/SQL. I mean: if it is too difficult to put all logic into a single query (not that it can not be written, but - who is going to maintain it? Two months later you won't even remember why exactly you wrote *this* instead of *that*). In a (stored) function, you have another level of flexibility and use IFs, CASEs or whatever you  might need. If the result isn't one row but more of them, let the function return a *table* which you can use in Apex as `select * from table(your_function(:P2_TEST_TYPE));`

Comment: That two-month rule becomes even more important if you will be handing that code off to anyone else.  A PL/SQL block can (and should) be extensively commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to split the logic between the two regions and then use show/hide to display an appropriate region

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that both subqueries are quite resembling, I suggest you extract to a single subquery all the common `AND` conditions, and include an additional `OR` for each alternative condition. Then, group each set of conditions by their common sub-conditions (the one regarding `b.status`):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.NAME
FROM Table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM   Table2 b
    WHERE  b.id = a.id            
        AND b.type_id = :P2_TEST_TYPE
        AND
        (
            (
                b.status = 'NEW' AND
                (
                    (
                        mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE)) IN ('TYPE1', 'TYPE2')
                        AND
                        mypackage.get_category_id(b.parent_id) <> mypackage.get_category_id(:P2_PARENT_ID)
                    )
                    OR (mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE)) = 'TYPE3')
                )
            )
            OR 
            (
                b.status <> 'NEW' AND
                (
                       (mypackage.get_role(a.id) = 'PRIMARY' AND mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE))='TYPE4')
                    OR (mypackage.get_role(a.id) = 'SECONDARY' AND mypackage.get_type_id(TO_NUMBER(:P2_TEST_TYPE))='TYPE5')
                )
            )
        )
);
```

Certainly, it throws too much complexity. You should consider using a client language procedure instead.